# CALayer = Total lag

Tags: iphone, uibutton, calayer

So I have a scrollView with like 10 buttons on one side. Always when I scroll to that page, I get lots of bad performance. Then I noticed it was the CALayer that was creating the lag! I've used

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
button.layer.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

When I searched on the internet, I found out that I could use

```
button.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

it should work better. But it just lowered the resolution and did not improve the performance. So I tried cutting the edges off in GIMP, but when I added them to XCode, they got filled in with white! So, please, tell me, is there any way that I can round corners without bad performance, by CALayer or without, doesn't matter. Any help appreciated!

(ps. if you need the whole code or image, tell me and I'll add it)

UPDATE:

It only works with bad performance on the iPhone 4, I tried it on my iPad Mini, and it worked just fine!

Comment: When I began rasterizing my rounded corner and shadow layers, I definitely saw a notable increase in performance, so I am not sure why you are not. However, I think that adding the following will solve your lower resolution issues: `button.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;`

Comment: You aren't using shadows, are you? If you are, then the biggest performance increase will come from setting the shadow path.

Comment: Thank uou for your answer @Mathew, I'll add the scale to rasterize and check if I'm using shadows (I'll do it tomorrow, since I'm on my iPad right now)

Comment: @Mathew the rasterizationscale worked, but I'm not sure how I can disable shadows.

Comment: well, you probably aren't using shadows unless you enabled them in the first place. To my knowledge, they are never on by default. However, the relevant layer properties are `layer.shadowOpacity`, `layer.shadowRadius`, `layer.shadowOffset`, `layer.shadowPath`, and the rasterization code you are already using. To disable shadows, you simply set `shadowOpacity = 0`.

Comment: well, thanks for the answer, but no, the shadow disabling didn't change anything, sadly

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has commented on this but what does Instruments tell you? Any unnecessary blending, off-screen rendering? What is your device utilization % of the GPU (are you bound by CPU or GPU)? Are you redrawing anything during scrolling? With rasterizertion on, do you have any cache misses? All of those are things you should check first. Always measure!

Comment: Yes, thanks @DavidRönnqvist but I have a question: How do I check all of those things?

Comment: I always used `cornerRadius` without `clipsToBounds`, see if this helps. Otherwise if you use GIMP for adding corners you have to set the view's `opaque` value to `NO` ;) (png of course. But you should use the background color of the cell [if possible] -> better performance with `opaque = YES;`)

Comment: @relikd Without clipsToBounds, XCode doesn't create corners. But the opaque saved my life! Please create an answer, for acceptation and bounty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create those images with GIMP like you suggested. The key to success is to set the `opaque` value of the view to `NO`, which means to enable transparency. But remember that setting a view's opaque value to NO can result in loss of performance especially in fast changing views like `UIScrollViewCell`.

In your case it's fast enough, in other cases maybe not. If the background is a single color, it is better to use that color as background color in your image manipulation program. (and set `opaque = YES;`)

Comment: Oh, and I also realised that the image needs to be .png  . 
.jpg doesn't  work

Comment: yep, because jpg doesn't support transparency ;D